# Selenium Webdriver switchTo() method fails in Chrome 75

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Switching to an open tab with Selenium works fine in Chrome 74. However, in 75 I get this message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
```

Does anyone else encounter this and how can this be solved except for pinning the Chrome version to 74?

Comment: Did you upgrade `chromedriver`?

Comment: Yes it is the latest chromedriver.

Comment: I found out that this works locally with the updated webdriver. However, with the same remote webdriver version, this fails on BrowserStack.

Comment: I've downgraded to Chrome 74 on BrowserStack and everything works fine now.

Comment: I solved this by removing the browserstack.selenium_version capability.

If you don't set a specific remote selenium version, Chrome 75 works too.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the error by adding the below browserstack specific capability in my tests-

```
'browserstack.use_w3c' : 'true'
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, this is currently an issue with the latest version of Edge (Sept 2020) on BrowserStack.  This resolves the problem.

Comment: Faced the same issue on Chrome 93 as well and the above answer helped fix it. Guess it might be the same for other Chromium based browsers as well.