# OpenQA.Selenium Error: 'invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having some issues switching to new window while carrying out remote testing using Selenium.
I had no problem when testing this locally , but when testing it remotely, it keeps bringing up "handle" must be a string error. I have checked my code and ensured my window argument is a string. Someone please help out.

Below is the code and the generated error.

```
    public static void SwitchToLoginWindow(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        // Wait for the popup to appear
        ReadOnlyCollection<string> wh;

        int timeCount = 1;
        do
        {
            wh = webDriver.WindowHandles;
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            timeCount++;
            if (timeCount > 50)
            {
                break;
            }
        } 

        while (wh.Count == 1);

        //Thread.Sleep(500);
        //int numberOfWindows = wh.Count;
        var numberOfWindow = wh.Count;
        Console.WriteLine($"Switching to Azure AD login popup. Return URL is {webDriver.Url}");
        Thread.Sleep(200);

        webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(wh[numberOfWindow - 1]);
        Waiters.ExplicitWait(webDriver, SelectorType.CssSelector, AzureAd.UserNameField);
    }
```

**Exception Error**

Thrown here:

```
webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(wh[numberOfWindow - 1]);
```

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
>     (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.90)
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
>   System info: host: '8f5340ba4bc2', ip: '172.21.0.12', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-145-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown'

Comment: Any help from this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538895/selenium-webdriver-switchto-method-fails-in-chrome-75

Comment: I am having the same issue, but only in Edge browser. The issue is not 100% reproducible, all browsers work good, Edge is about 80% failing with the same exception.

Comment: I am having the same issue in Edge. Someone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the code below helped me to get rid of the error. You have to do this when initializing the chrome driver:

```
    public IWebDriver GetRemoteChromeDriver(string downloadPath)
    {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadPath); //just setting he download path
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox"); //this line is here due another issue, so it isn't necessary
        chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("w3c", false); //this is the relevant line that hopefully will solve the problem
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver", @"c:\BuildTools\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"); //
        ICapabilities capability = chromeOptions.ToCapabilities();

        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capability);

        return driver;
    }
```

**This is a bug with latest chrome. It now supports the W3C spec by default and there is no need to pass that option. If it is passed, this bug occurs.**

I found this solution on [this](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4187) topic on github, it did the job done for me, I hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

'invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
I had this Selenium issue and solved it temporarily by changing from Selenium version 3.141.59 to 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

For users getting this error while executing tests on Browserstack on Chrome version 93 with selenium 3(specifically 3.14), my issue got resolved by adding `browserstack.use_w3c : true`

By default, Browserstack runs the tests on non-w3c mode. If we want to enable w3c spec, we need to pass it explicitly.

**Note:** While using the above capability to set w3c spec format, make sure that your other capabilities are w3c compliant. Else, those would be ignored and only the w3c compliant ones would be retained while creating the webdriver session.